# Access to Custom objects for Customer Portal Users

Tags: sharing, permissions, profile, customer-portal, sharing-sets

We have customer portal and We have exposed Custom objects that have lookup to Account object and private sharing
to Customer portal users. This is done by adding the sharing set such that User's Account matches with account lookup
on Custom object. We have created custom profile having high volume customer portal license.

Once the sharing set is added, do I have to explicitly give "Object Permission" and "field Permission" to custom object
for Portal Profile ?

what I see is, Portal User can access the custom object after adding sharing set and without having any "object Permission"
and "field Permission" for the custom object.

Any insight on this would be very helpful.

Comment: When you login as a portal user, can that portal user see every field on the custom object, even if that field is not given to that user via Profile or Permission Set?

Comment: @DavidSchach, Yes, when I login as portal user, portal user can see every field on the custom object. confirmed it with debug logs